# Insert value based on min value greater than value in another row

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, alias

It's difficult to explain the question well in the title.

I am inserting 6 values from (or based on values in) one row.
I also need to insert a value from a second row where:

1. The values in one column (`ID`) must be equal
2. The values in column (`CODE`) in the main source row must be IN (100,200), whereas the other row must have value of 300 or 400
3. The value in another column (`OBJID`) in the secondary row must be the lowest value above that in the primary row.

Source Table looks like:

```
OBJID | CODE | ENTRY_TIME | INFO | ID | USER
---------------------------------------------
   1  | 100  | x timestamp| .... | 10 |  X
   2  | 100  | y timestamp| .... | 11 |  Y
   3  | 300  | z timestamp| .... | 10 |  F
   4  | 100  | h timestamp| .... | 10 |  X
   5  | 300  | g timestamp| .... | 10 |  G
```

So to provide an example..
In my second table I want to insert `OBJID`, `OBJID2`, `CODE`, `ENTRY_TIME`, `substr(INFO(...))`, `ID`, `USER`

i.e. from my example a line inserted in the second table would look like:

```
OBJID | OBJID2 | CODE | ENTRY_TIME | INFO      | ID | USER
-----------------------------------------------------------
   1  |    3   | 100  | x timestamp| substring | 10 |  X
   4  |    5   | 100  | h timestamp| substring2| 10 |  X
```

My insert for everything that just comes from one row works fine.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
(ID, OBJID, INFO, USER, ENTRY_TIME)
SELECT ID, OBJID, DECODE(CODE, 100, (SUBSTR(INFO, 12, 
LENGTH(INFO)-27)),                                                           
600,'CREATE') INFO, USER, ENTRY_TIME
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CODE IN (100,200);
```

I'm aware that I'll need to use an alias on `TABLE1`, but I don't know how to get the rest to work, particularly in an efficient way. There are 2 million rows right now, but there will be closer to 20 million once I start using production data.

Comment: Better than giving you a solution here, I suggest you create a view, where to put all of you logic and get the expected output the way you want it. Then execute the insert statement as select from this new view.

Comment: Can you complete the output table for us? Please give us all the rows for it. It is hard to understand what you want from current specifications.

Comment: @FlorinGhita 
If I could complete the output table then I wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place. From the example rows I've given in the first table, there is only one possible complete row in the second table.

Comment: @Slingy I need that only for the input set you gave. Not the code, but the test data. For example for objid = 4 the coresponding objid2 is 5, isn't it?

Comment: @FlorinGhita Yes, actually you're correct. I missed that.
Edited the OP.

Comment: By 'cell', do you mean column value? Also what is your Oracle version?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I used the word "cell" because I didn't know what else to call it. I'm not formally trained in anything to do with databases or SQL, so I struggle to find the correct terms or explain problems clearly sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select primary.* ,
    (select min(objid)
    from table1 secondary
    where primary.objid < secondary.objid 
        and secondary.code in (300,400) 
        and primary.id = secondary.id
    ) objid2
from table1 primary
where primary.code in (100,200);
```

Comment: Strange aliases, but nice solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've come up with:

```
select  OBJID, 
        min(case when code in (300,400) then  objid end) 
          over (partition by id order by objid 
                range between 1  following and unbounded following
                ) objid2,
        CODE, ENTRY_TIME, INFO, ID, USER1
from table1;
```

So, you need a `insert select` the above query with a `where objid2 is not null` and code in (100,200);